# Ionic: Icon doesn't switch back when using *ngIf

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

So I have the following button in Ionic:

HTML

```
<button ion-button (click)="play()">
   <ion-icon *ngIf="!isPlaying" name="play"></ion-icon>
   <ion-icon *ngIf="isPlaying" name="stop"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Component

```
play() {
  this.isPlaying = true;
  this.nativeAudio.play('audioId', () => {
    this.isPlaying = false;
  });
}
```

Right now when I click the button the icon switches to stop which indicates the play has started. But when after playing even when I set the `isPlaying` to false the button still shows the `stop` icon.

Now in my view there are different buttons and I noticed that when I press one of the other buttons the icon now switches to the `play` icon. It almost seems like the UI doesn't refresh until there's another activity on the UI. This also happens when I try to switch displayed images using `*ngIf`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add the piece of code where you're toggling `isPlaying`? Otherwise it'll be hard to reproduce your issue. Maybe you can even create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) that demonstrates your issue

Comment: Added the component code above.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
play(){
   this.isPlaying = ! this.isPLaying;
}
```

in your `html` file

```
<button ion-button (click)="play()">
   <ion-icon [name]="!isPlaying? 'play':'stop'"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How about if i'm toggling an `ion-icon` and an `img` tag inside the button? How should it look?

Comment: Can you update that in your question? So that I will get a clear picture